# Deploy Django Project with Apache, shows files instead of /admin site

Tags: python, django, macos, apache

I'm trying to deploy my Django Project with Apache, but after 3 days, I can't figure out where is my mistake or what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using this:
Macbook Pro with OSX El Capitan 10.11.4
Python 2.7
Django 1.9.5
Apache 2.4.18

I have a Virtual Environment under this path:
*~/Sites/EnvLimber*

And I have my Django Project under this path (here's the manage.py):
*~/Sites/EnvLimber/limber*

I've installed mod_wsgi with HomeBrew, and also, my python server runs fine with python manage.py runserver.

My URL for the site is app.limber.com, and when I reach there, I have this output:

[app.limber.com at Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1DyY.png)

If I try /login or /admin I've the 404 Not Found error.

Here's my virtual host configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Mauricio/Sites/EnvLimber"
    ServerName app.limber.com
    ErrorLog "/Users/Mauricio/Sites/logs/app.limber.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/Users/Mauricio/Sites/logs/app.limber.com-access_log" common
    <Directory "/Users/Mauricio/Sites/EnvLimber/limber">
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    LogLevel info

    ServerName app.limber.com
    ServerAdmin maurigmorra@gmail.com

    # Static files
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Mauricio/Sites/EnvLimber/limber"
    Alias /static/ /Users/Mauricio/Sites/EnvLimber/limber/static/

    <Directory "/Users/Mauricio/Sites/EnvLimber/limber/static">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # WGSI configuration
    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/Users/Mauricio/EnvLimber/Limber/:/Users/Mauricio/Sites/EnvLimber/lib/python2.7/site-packages

    WSGIProcessGroup app.limber.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/Mauricio/EnvLimber/limber/limber/wsgi.py

    <Directory "/Users/Mauricio/EnvLimber/limber/limber">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I will really appreciate the help, and I hope that my question will help someone more.
I apologize about my grammar, English isn't my first language.

Comment: You're hosting the site on your laptop?

Comment: Yes I'm. I want to deploy it at localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have two VirtualHost sections. Move the error log directives into the second section, and delete the first one completely.

Comment: Excellent! But now I have Forbidden You don't have permission to access /admin on this server. The permissions on the ~/Sites folder should be 755?

Comment: [Thu Apr 21 14:44:10.848001 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 7601] [client 127.0.0.1:56030] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /Users/Mauricio/EnvLimber

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName app.limber.com
ServerAdmin maurigmorra@gmail.com

WSGIDaemonProcess / python-path=/Users/Mauricio/Sites/EnvLimber/limber:/Users/Mauricio/Sites/EnvLimber/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup /

Alias /static /Users/Mauricio/Sites/EnvLimber/limber/static

<Directory /Users/Mauricio/EnvLimber/limber/limber/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/Mauricio/Sites/EnvLimber/limber/limber/wsgi.py

<Directory /Users/Mauricio/Sites/EnvLimber/limber>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```